# Cannot read private member #form from an object whose class did not declare it

Tags: javascript, class, closures, this, private

I'm unable to access a private method that was used as an argument for a submitted event. The use of `this` now points to the form rather than the class itself. what is the easiest way to reference a class irrespective of object depth or closure in javascript?

```
class payment {
    
    #form;
    
    constructor() {
        this.#form = $('#code-form').get(0);
        this.#form.addEventListener('submit', this.#submitForm);
    }

    
    #submitForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        console.log( this.#form ); // Cannot read private member #form from an object whose class did not declare it
    }

}

(new payment());
```

Comment: @MisterJojo - By the use of `addEventListener('submit', x)`, it shouldn't be too difficult to know that `$('#code-form')` is a `<form>` element!

Comment: @MisterJojo - The problem here is not about the `<form>`. Even if the form contains just one submit button and nothing else, it still fulfills its purpose. There is nothing weird about the form. The problem you should be concerned about is the `this` keyword and how it can point to the `payment` class

Comment: @MisterJojo - I've edited the code! This doesn't require too many question or re-editing of code. The problem is clearly visible even from the minimal code

Comment: I have no imagination for this kind of thing, would you be blaming me for it? on the other hand, unlike you, I know how to use a debugger.

Comment: Instead of `'submit', this.#submitForm`, do `'submit', (e) => this.#submitForm(e)` so you retain the correct `this` context (see duplicate for more info)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bind` in the constructor or when adding the event listener 1.

Here is an example using bind:

```js
class payment {
    #form;

    constructor() {
        this.#form = $('#code-form').get(0);
        this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
        this.#form.addEventListener('submit', this.submitForm);
    }

    submitForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.#form);
    }
}

(new payment());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="code-form">
        <button type="submit"></button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I just tried out the above code and got the following error - Private method '#submitForm' is not writable at new payment.

Comment: However, I tried it by removing the `#` and it works fine if the `submitForm` method is made public.

Comment: I made an edit, try again now.

Comment: It works now when the `submitForm` method is made public. Thank you

Comment: I ran into this error by having a class with a public field `pub = new Map();`, a private field `#key;`, and a public method that internally calls `this.pub.get(this.#key)`. I have no idea why it doesn't work but this solution fixed it for me.